# Syntax.NormalizeWhitespace() Missing?

Tags: roslyn

There is some code which use `SyntaxExtensions.NormalizeWhitespace()`.
I cannot find the method inside recent `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp` releases.

Is there a quick way to format syntax using roslyn?

Comment: Use `Formatter.Format/FormatAsync()` in conjunction with a span or `Formatter.Annotation`.

Answer (score 0):

The method is still there. It's surfaced as an extension method on [SyntaxNode](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNodeExtensions.cs,290), [SyntaxToken](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxExtensions.cs,63), and [SyntaxList](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxExtensions.cs,92).

The easiest way to use this is to call the method on an existing `SyntaxNode`. For example, in a code fix, I might do something like this:

```
var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
var newRoot = root.NormalizeWhitespace();
Document updatedDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
```

Comment: I finally found that extension inside Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll.